# Rename active directory account name

Tags: active-directory, user-accounts, rename

I have an existing user account within active directory. I'm using the naming convention "MyApp-dev" for dev, "MyApp-qa" for qa and so forth, up to prod.

Our IT services department wanted to rename these accounts to "myapp-dev-service", i.e. all lowercase and post fix with service, because these accounts are used to host services. All was okay.

We renamed the accounts. We reconfigured our IIS application pool identities and Windows services logon credentials to match the new account names. All was okay.

When I profile SQL Server I still see the services connecting to the database with  the old account name. I used Active Directory Explorer v1.2 by Bryce Cogswell and Mark Russinovich to look at the account properties within Active Directory. Everything seems to be okay.

Can anybody suggest what is going on, why I still see the old account name? Is it SQL profiler or Active Directory or just a synchronization problem? Or is it something that I completely missed?

Comment: This might be a better question to ask a www.ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

You should also rename the logins in SQL Server.